# Mixed effects model with baseline values as a fixed effect

Tags: r, mixed-models

My study was a 12 week long study involving two diets (diet). Outcome measurements such as weight, waist circumference etc. were taken at time (time) = 0,6,and 12 week intervals. (Code) stands for subjects. Recall stands for number of dietary recall questionnaire; there are 3. Kcal is caloric intake gathered from a given recall.

This is what the data frame looks like

`code treatment time weight recall kcal
  1         a    1     80      1 1500
  1         a    2     78      2 1400
  1         a    3     75      3 1450
  2         b    1     82      1 1600
  2         b    2     81      2 1700
  2         b    3     81      3 1650
  3         a    1     95      1 1200
  3         a    2     90      2 1100
  3         a    3     85      3 1150
  4         b    1     97      1 1900
  4         b    2     95      2 1850
  4         b    3     96      3 1875`

I would like to create a model where I use weight at time = 1 as a fixed effect. And weight at time = 2 and time = 3 as outcome.

I learnt here yesterday how to do weight at time = 1 as fixed effect. I used the following code.

```
mydata <- mydata[order(mydata$code, mydata$time), ]
mydata$weight1 <- with(my data, ave(weight, code, FUN = function (x) x[1]))
```

This is my model

```
lmer(weight ~ treatment * time + weight1 + weight1 * time + (time | code), REML = FALSE, data = mydata)
```

However, in this model the outcome 'weight' is outcome at time =1,2 and 3. How do I limit this outcome to just 'weight' at post baseline values of time = 2 and time = 3?

Thanks for your help and taking the time to read this post.

Comment: Why do you want to condition on the baseline weight outcome in your fixed effects? Your model includes random intercepts and this postulates that subjects have different weights at baseline.

Comment: I wasn't originally planning on doing this. However, I was suggested in another thread that there is value in using weight as fixed effect in addition to using random intercepts. Is this redundant? Could there by any value in adding baseline weight * time as an interaction effect in the model?

Here is the thread in question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331791/baseline-adjustment-in-mixed-models

Comment: It can depend on your data. For example, if you have a very sudden drop or increase from baseline to the second measurement. But most often I'd say it is not needed.

Comment: I see, I have a large difference in baseline measurements on the two different treatments. Would baseline as a fixed effect add any extra value here apart from random intercepts/random slopes?